# Copying parent element namespace to child namespace in java

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I am using java to to generate an xml file. The namespace that is used for parent element has to be copied to the child element as well. I know that the namespaces in the parent node also get reflected to the child nodes, but the external system expects namespaces for both the nodes.
Below is the code I've tried in java. The namespace gets added to the the parent node successfully but not to the child node.

```
Element root = doc.createElement("ResultSet");
root.setAttribute("xmlns:ns2", "http://www.dummy.com/xsd/tublu/murmur_001");
doc.appendChild(root);

Element child = doc.createElement("Result");
child.setAttribute("xmlns:ns2", "http://www.dummy.com/xsd/tublu/murmur_001");
child.setAttribute("Flag", "true");
child.appendChild(root);
```

Is there any way I can achieve it using java? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you should experiment with the -NS variants of the DOM methods, e.g. `doc.createElementNS("http://www.dummy.com/xsd/tublu/murmur_001", "ResultSet");`

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't give an option to add the name for the namespace. I get it as <Result xmlns="http://www.dummy.com/xsd/tublu/murmur_001">. I want it to be like <Result xmlns:ns2="http://www.dummy.com/xsd/tublu/murmur_001">

Comment: How are you writing the XML?

Comment: The second argument to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html#createElementNS-java.lang.String-java.lang.String- can be e.g. `"ns2:Result"`. It is not quite clear what you want to achieve, use `createElementNS` if you want to create an element in a certain namespace; if your object is to add a namespace declaration attribute for a secondary namespace then you can use e.g. `setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/", "xmlns:ns2", "http://www.dummy.com/xsd/tublu/murmur_001");`